# Using String.ValueOf() to convert Float to String in selenium shows the exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to [C

Tags: java, rest, web-services, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying run some tests related to REST APIs using Selenium. As per the below code I need to convert a Float value into String.

When i use String.valueOf(float arg), I get the exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to [C

Code:

```
@Test

public void Test01()
{
    Response r=given().parameter("id", "someID").parameter("appid", "someID").when().get("someURL");

    String lon=String.valueOf(r.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path("coord.lon"));

    System.out.println(lon);
}
```

Expected: Value conversion must be successful. i.e., Float -> String

Actual: 
FAILED: Test01

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to [C
    at APITestingProject.com.org.api.TransferingAPIResponse_2.Test01(TransferingAPIResponse_2.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact exception as in `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to [C.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code

```
String lon=String.valueOf(r.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path("coord.lon"));
```

Need to use Float.toString() method

```
String lon=Float.toString(r.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path("coord.lon"));
```

if need more information visit this website
http://javadevnotes.com/java-float-to-string-examples